# Corrupt email attachment with python

Tags: python, gmail, attachment

I am trying to send a compressed folder as an email attachment from a gmail account to a gmail account.

I have no problem when I send simple .txt files, but whatever compression type I use, I cannot successfully send a compressed file. Even if I compress a single file, it is corrupted when I download it back from Gmail. I've tried several things, like encrypting the file first with `ccrypt` and then send it. The file is still corrupt.

This does not apply if I send the email normally, from my browser, with the same attachment. That makes me wonder whether it is Gmail or the code I use to blame.

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os, re
import sys
import smtplib

from email import encoders
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText


SMTP_SERVER = 'smtp.gmail.com'
SMTP_PORT = 587


sender = 'email@gmail.com'
password = "password"
recipient = sys.argv[1]
subject = ''
message = sys.argv[3]

def main():
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['Subject'] = sys.argv[2]
    msg['To'] = recipient
    msg['From'] = sender

    part = MIMEText('text', "plain")
    part.set_payload(message)
    msg.attach(part)

    session = smtplib.SMTP(SMTP_SERVER, SMTP_PORT)

    session.ehlo()
    session.starttls()
    session.ehlo

    session.login(sender, password)

    fp = open(sys.argv[4], 'rb')
    msgq = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
    msgq.set_payload(fp.read())
    fp.close()
    # Encode the payload using Base64
    filename=sys.argv[4]
    msgq.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=filename)
    msg.attach(msgq)
    # Now send or store the message
    qwertyuiop = msg.as_string()

    session.sendmail(sender, recipient, qwertyuiop)

    session.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It is used as:

```
./send_email.py receiver@gmail.com "title" "body" attachment.rar
```

and you should fill in your login details on top of the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the comment `# Encode the payload using Base64` try this... `encoders.encode_base64(msgq)`

Comment: I wrote a similar script just few days back and faced a similar issue :)